# How to specify electron-wix-msi to create admin shortcuts?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

So I have made an installer using electron-wix-msi and electron-packager.

In electron packager I specified that the exe must be executed with admin and it works perfectly, the problem is when I package it into an msi the shortcuts do not run with admin privileges and so the app will not run. Is there any way around this?

Thanks